# Stroke-linecap is screwing my paths in Raphael.. is there a way to make it round towards the "inside" of the path?

Tags: raphael

I am trying to draw a simple donut shaped graph with two paths: one showing the amount, the other showing the missing area in grey.

Here is the jsfiddle doing exactly that: http://jsfiddle.net/e2J89/

Problem: if I add `"stroke-linecap":"round"` the linecap stretches the paths, screwing up all my calculations.

```
var solved = paper.path().attr({
    "stroke": "#f00",
    "stroke-width": 14,
    "stroke-linecap":"round",
    arc: [center_x, center_y, 0, total_amount, radius]
});
```

Is there a simple way to fix this, or do I have to recompute the starting points/amounts differently? (and would it depend on the stroke-width, too?)

```
var solved_amount = amount;
var unsolved_amount = total_amount - solved_amount;

var solved_start = (180 * unsolved_amount/100 + start_delta) % 360;
var unsolved_start = (360 / total_amount * solved_amount + solved_start) % 360;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stroke-linecap: round` draws an arc with center on the end of the path with radius equal to half the stroke width.

[See SVG spec for diagram](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeLinecapProperty)

You would have to adjust your arc lengths if you want round line caps. Also, how would you handle small percentages? The round line caps will be drawn even with a zero length line.